# Using javascript to open new tab and reload parent page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hyperlink, reload

I have a wordpress theme with a logo linking to a .pdf document.
In order to link the logo to the document, I must use a custom javascript :

```
document.getElementById('logo').href = "javascript:window.open('mylink')"
```

I want this document open in a new tab. It currently works but for some reasons, I need to reload the parent page after the new tab has opened.

What can I add in order reload the parent page ? 
Thanks

Comment: So you are saying if you click on logo, it opens a new tab, but then if you click again, it does not work?

Comment: What reasons do you need to reload the page for?

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for your answer. No, actually the parent page goes blank just after the new tab has opened so I need to reload it. I don't know if there is a simpler solution but ;location.reload()" do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you've asked you can make a small simple change...

```
document.getElementById('logo').href = "javascript:window.open('mylink');location.reload()";
```

However, without knowing why you need to refresh the page I can't say this is the best course of action.  We need more information to be able to help you more appropriately.

**Edit**
Now that you've explained why you need to reload the page (it goes blank when you click the link), you should change your previous code to this, in order to stop that happening...

```
var link = document.getElementById('logo');
link.href = "url_of_the_pdf";
link.target = "_blank";
```

Previously the output from `window.open()` was being written to the page, which caused the current page contents to be deleted.  This method changes the link so that it works correctly, and should resolve your previous problem.

Comment: Thanks Archer. This simple change solved the problem.
Actually after the new tab has opened, the parent page goes blank so I need to reload it. I don't know if there is a simpler solution but this works.

Comment: In that case, I'll add a bit more code to this answer to solve that problem.

Comment: Done.  Is there a reason you can't modify the link itself, rather than alter it with Javascript?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this solution is better. 
Honestly, I don't know how to do it. I'm a newbie in Wordpress architecture. 
The logo previously linked to the homepage. I have contacted the support team of the wordpress theme to know how I can change the link. They gave the script above as a solution but I still had this parent page problem.
I could modify that link if I look for the specific file but I not sure I'll do it properly.

Comment: Fair enough.  If it's part of the template then you will be able to change it, but the script solution will suffice.  As long as you get there in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a onclick="open_in_new_tab_and_reload('./path_to_pdf.pdf')" href="#">PDF</a>

<script>
function open_in_new_tab_and_reload(url)
{
  //Open in new tab
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  //focus to thet window
  window.focus();
  //reload current page
  location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for that. You can wrap the logo in a `<a href="yourlink"></a>` tag. Then, use the `target` attribute to tell it to open in a new tab.

```
<a target="_blank" href="yourlink"><img src="yourlogo"...></img></a>
```

Comment: And how does this reload the main page?

Comment: @Teemu I understood there is a problem that solves itself when reloading the main page. I thought he might avoid it alltogether by not using js at all.

Comment: @ThatBrianDude
Thanks. 
Actually after the new tab has opened, the parent page goes blank so I need to reload it. I don't know if there is a simpler solution but I can solve  it using ;location.reload()